# reload local jsonp file as variable in website

Tags: javascript, json

I have a local webpage that loads a large json database file by having a file called data.jsonp containing data={json dictionary of stuff}, then importing said file in my HTML with `<script src="data.jsonp"></script>` to load data as a variable containing the whole database, which works.

I now need to be able to change the content of the data.jsonp file and have the data variable update without refresing the whole website. I can edit data.jsonp, but how do I apply this change to the data variable?

Answer (score 0):

Add another `<script>` tag to the DOM, and it will reload the script:

```
let script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "data.jsonp";
document.head.appendChild(script);
```